# Pass List <String> parameter by value instead of by reference

Tags: list, kotlin, parameter-passing, onclicklistener

I have a code like this

```
val myFirstList = mutableListOf("Hello", "You can ", "edit, ", "run, ", "and share this code")
for (i in 0..myFirstList.size-2) {
    myFun(myFirstList)    
}
```

and a function like this

```
fun myFun (myList: MutableList<String>){
    myList.removeAt(0)
    println(myList)
 }
```

The output is:

> [You can , edit, , run, , and share this code]
>
> [edit, , run, , and > share this code]
>
> [run, , and share this code]
>
> [and share this code]

but I need it always (only 1st string removed):

> [You can , edit, , run, , and share this code]

I found a workaround like this:

```
myFun(myFirstList.toList().toMutableList())
```

but I'm sure there is a better solution to pass the list by value instead of by reference.

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: If you need to keep printing the same list, why are you calling `removeAt(0)` on it?

Comment: @Mureinik I need to remove only the 1st string

Comment: why not remove it outside the loop?

Comment: @Mureinik I need it elsewhere but I need it to be removed in the fun excution. It could be useful to pass only from 2nd String but I wasn't able to do that without a lot of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking about the "passing a list by value": no, there isn't a better solution. What you call "passing by value" actually requires creating a full copy of the whole list. As such operation is pretty heavy on resources, it doesn't happen implicitly - we have to do it explicitly. You can skip `toList()` and keep only: `myFirstList.toMutableList()`, so we don't copy the data twice.

However, speaking about your specific case, maybe there are better options than creating a copy, but it all depends on your needs. If you always only remove the first item, then maybe you should do it once, outside the `myFun()` and reuse the same, already cut list. You could also try: `myList.subList(1, myList.size)`. It creates a view of the list, so it doesn't copy the data, but only wraps the original list. But again, it all depends on your specific case.

Comment: In my case I opted for `myList.subList` (it was what I was looking for)